# PendingIntent used with Broadcast Receiver not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm to register a BroadcastReceiver and passing it a id that I would like to display when the broadcast is received.

What i want to do is to access the database entries at a particular instance (ie when the alarm goes off)thats the reason i pass id through intent

```
View.OnClickListener saveHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");

        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        objalarmManger = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(mContext,
                MyBroadCastReceiver.class);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("id",22);
        PendingIntent objPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0,
                broadcastIntent, 0);

        Calendar objC = Calendar.getInstance();
        objC.set(yearData, monthData, dayData, hour, min);
        objalarmManger.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, objC.getTimeInMillis(),
                objPI);
    }
};
```

The Broadcast receiver code is

```
public class MyBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

    int id = arg1.getIntExtra("id", 0);

    Toast.makeText(arg0, id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("Received", id + "");
}
```

}

I'm not able to see any log cat entiers,is there anything wrong in the code implementation.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What do you mean by, "no working"? Crashing, just not displaying `Toast`, etc... Also, is your `BroadcastReceiver` registered in your `manifest`?

Comment: How do you register this BroadcastReceiver? Are you sure that the time  used to create the alarm is correct?

Comment: @codeMagic yes I have registered BroadcastReceiver in my manifest file
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadCastReceiver" >
        </receiver>
By not working i mean it doesn't display the toast neither does it shows any entries in logcat

Comment: @Egor Yes I get the current time and add one min to it
Haven't put that code here but, thats what i do.

Comment: You should check the value of the time parameter that you pass to `AlarmManager`. Add logging to output that value and verify that it is correct. Sounds to me like your time is wrong.

Comment: Did you get a solution to your problem, what was it ?